# Как подключить прокси лист к php

Tags: php, прокси

Использую на сайте такой код:

```
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_URL,$_url);
global $proxy;
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
global $curlopt_useragent;
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$curlopt_useragent);
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "file/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($options, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "file/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS,1);
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
$loops=1;
$loops_max=20;
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($options,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

`$proxy` подключаются по одному, что очень не удобно. Как можно изменить код так, что бы прокси случано брались по url-ссылке (т.е. `1/10/241/7/16` по счету) или случайно брались с текстового файла

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как вариант:

```
$proxies = file_get_contents('proxies.txt'); //тут можно и урл написать, вместо имени файла
$proxies_array = array_values(array_unique(explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $proxies))));

$proxy = $proxies_array[rand(0, count($proxies_array))];
```

Comment: `file` уже делит по переносам строк. Просто `trim` для всех.